# I try to install caffe on windows

Tags: python, computer-vision, caffe, conv-neural-network

I try to install caffe on windows from https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/opencl

When I build by build_win.cmd I get these errors

```
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:211 (add_dependencies):
  The dependency target "pycaffe" of target "pytest" does not exist.


-- Generating done
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    BUILD_python_layer
    CUDA_ARCH_NAME
    USE_CUDNN
    USE_INDEX64


-- Build files have been written to: D:/Professionnel/Projets/2017/caffe/build
ERROR: Configure failed

D:\Professionnel\Projets\2017\caffe>
```

Comment: Finally I installed Numpy by : `pip install numpy` and it works